# HttpClient ContinueWith Integration Test without the awaiting

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

**Background**

This code runs on a little RaspberryPi connected to a GPS device. The GPS device sends GPS data (Latitude and Longitude) to the RaspberryPi which in turn fires off that data to a service on Amazon Web Services (the cloud). It is for Car telematics.

**Problem**

I wish to write an Integration Test to make sure that when the `PostAsync` to the cloud fails, something is logged via the logger. My code looks like this:

```
private void PostMovementToCloud(TelematicsAppEvent telemetryEvent)
{
    var messageContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(telemetryEvent));
    messageContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeJson;

    var result = _webClient.Value.PostAsync(GetEventEndPoint(telemetryEvent), messageContent, CancellationToken);
    result.ContinueWith(t => { ContinuationSteps(t, result); });
}

private void ContinuationSteps(Task<HttpResponseMessage> t, Task<HttpResponseMessage> result)
{
    if (t.IsFaulted || !result.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
    {
        // want to ensure this runs when the post to the cloud fails
        _logger.LogError(EventHttpClientError, () => $"Unable to post telemetry: {reason}");
    }
}
```

Readings from the GPS are fast and frequent, I do not want to do a `.Wait()` for each `PostAsync` because that will quickly slow down / crash the RaspberryPi. Instead, I want to fire off the requests without waiting for the response.

But when doing that, how can I test in an Integration Test that the code in the `ContinuationSteps` does indeed run?

**Integration Test Code**

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyTest
{
    private GpsSubscriberToJourneyEndPoint _gpsSubscriber;
    private readonly Mock<ITopicConsumer> _kafkaTopicConsumerMock = new Mock<ITopicConsumer>();

    [SetUp]
    public void RunBeforeAnyTests()
    {
        var gpsSubscriberToJourneyEndPointOptions = new GpsSubscriberToJourneyEndPointOptions
        {
            StartEndPoint = "journey-start-point-url",
            TimedEndPoint = "journey-mid-point-url",
            StopEndPoint = "journey-end-point-url"
        };

        var gpsSubscriberToJourneyEndPointOptionsMock = new Mock<IOptions<GpsSubscriberToJourneyEndPointOptions>>();
        var topicConsumerFactoryMock = new Mock<ITopicConsumerFactory>();
        var loggerMock = new Mock<ICharlesLogger>();
        var charlesLoggerFactoryMock = new Mock<ICharlesLoggerFactory>();

        gpsSubscriberToJourneyEndPointOptionsMock
            .SetupGet(o => o.Value)
            .Returns(gpsSubscriberToJourneyEndPointOptions);

        charlesLoggerFactoryMock
            .Setup(cl => cl.CreateLogger(It.IsAny<Type>()))
            .Returns(loggerMock.Object);

        topicConsumerFactoryMock
            .Setup(c => c.Create(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<IDictionary<string, string>>()))
            .Returns(_kafkaTopicConsumerMock.Object);

        _gpsSubscriber = new GpsSubscriberToJourneyEndPoint(
            gpsSubscriberToJourneyEndPointOptionsMock.Object,
            topicConsumerFactoryMock.Object, charlesLoggerFactoryMock.Object);
    }

    [Test]
    public void CheckFailingPostAsync()
    {
        // first and second reading have to be different in Lat and Lng to move the State machine to 'car moving state'
        const string firstGgaReading = "{\"Latitude\":53.639643,\"Longitude\":-1.782644,\"QualityIndicator\":2}";
        const string secondGgaReading = "{\"Latitude\":53.639399,\"Longitude\":-1.782834,\"QualityIndicator\":4}";
        _gpsSubscriber.Start(new CancellationToken());

        // Act
        // I'm raising the message received event here (message from gps device)
        _kafkaTopicConsumerMock
            .Raise(ktc => ktc.Message += null, new MessageEventArgs("Bam", firstGgaReading));

        _kafkaTopicConsumerMock
            .Raise(ktc => ktc.Message += null, new MessageEventArgs("Boom", secondGgaReading));
    }
}
```

Comment: Mock logger, post failing event then wait a bit for log entry to appear?

Comment: Added integration test code, when I debug that, the `ContinuationSteps` are never hit

Comment: Agree with martins answer below. Make it async all the way and await the PostAsync method inside PostMethodToCloud and convert PostMethodToCloud to returning `Task` and mark it async. Then the caller of `PostMethodToCloud` can decide if he wants to await it or do continue with. Also if this is a general purpose library (used not only in ASP.NET Core but also in ASP.NET, UWP, WPF, etc.) then also call `.ConfigureAwait(false)`

Comment: But you don't give them time to hit. You post 2 events, then test finishes and shuts down. You need some loop which checks if log event was received every X ms, and fail if it was not received after Y iterations of this loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should not create a fire-and-forget task anyway. If you create a `Task` and let it live, it may come back and bite you when you least expect it and you will have a hard time to find out what actually happened.

It would be best if the `PostMovementToCloud` method returned the `result` `Task` instance. Then you could await it in the test and you would be able to test it properly.

A hacky solution would involve artificial waiting (like `Task.Delay`) and then check of the result. If you are testing failing condition, you can probably make the task fail fast so any small delay should be sufficient. But as I say, this is hacky and not a good solution.

Comment: Yes something like this. You can keep the continuation there as well. The important thing is that you can access the `Task` and do not leave inaccessible to the caller.